# Is the social contract invalid if I change jurisdiction?

Tags: democracy, political-theory, taxes

Can I move to a different place and nullify the social contract (just somewhere else)?
Does this destroy the moral justification for taxes?

Comment: It's unclear what the parenthetical *"*(just somewhere else)*"  refers to.  Who or what specifically is somewhere else?

Comment: Hello user28055!  Welcome to Politics.SE.  Please read our [tour](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tour) page.

Answer (score 5):

The social contract is not a contract in the [legal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contract) sense, it is an abstraction to describe society in [moral and philosophical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract) debates.

You leave the social contract by leaving your society, i.e. by emigrating to another one or to a place where no other society exists (such places are hard to find on 21st century Earth). This puts the taxations of non-residents into question, not taxation in general.

Comment: But if I can change cities does that work.

Comment: @user28055, it will never "work" because the social contract is a moral concept. Rejecting a moral concept does not mean you have left the jurisdiction of the revenue service. Changing cities will get you a *different* municipal tax office.

Comment: But which jursdiction has the contract

Comment: @user28055, it is not a legal contract. It is a metaphor to describe the relationship between citizen and state with mutual rights and obligations.